# Differentiation of ${\sqrt{x}}^{{x}^{x..\infty}} $

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$y={\sqrt{x}}^{{x}^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^\infty}}}} $$ 
we got this problem now we are asked to find out $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of this , i have done a problem like this where we had $y={{x}}^{{x^{x{\cdot^{\cdot^\infty}}}}}$ where it was simpler to substitute power as $y=x^y$ then taking log and differentitating but in this problem square root is creating problem to express given problem in form simpler to differentiate

Comment: @Clayton, assuming the usual exponents rules apply on that weird-looking infinite exponent (?), both expressions are the same.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Doh! My brain left the building for a moment. Thanks!

Comment: I see, @Clayton...please do ask your brain whether by any chance he met mine out there: it left home some years ago and I haven't heard of it since.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$y^2=x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}\Rightarrow y^2=x^{y^2}\Rightarrow 2yy'=yx^{y^2-1}(y+2y'x\ln x)$$

Hence,

$$y'=\frac{y^2x^{y^2-1}}{2y-2yx^{y^2}\ln x}=\frac{\left(x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}\right)^2}{2x\sqrt{x}^{\ x^{x^{\cdots}}}\left(1-x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}\ln x\right)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $y(x)^2 = x^{y(x)^2}$. Now differentiate both sides:
$$
     2 y(x) y^{\prime}(x) = \left( \frac{y(x)^2}{x} + 2 y(x) y^{\prime}(x) \log(x) \right) \underbrace{x^{y(x)^2}}_{y(x)^2}
$$
Now solve for $y^{\prime}(x)$.